# $f$ continuous iff $f(K)$ is compact for all compact $K$.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

In topology, I have seen that $f$ is continuous if and only if $f^{-1}(U)$ is open when $U$ is open. But does it hold that $f$ continuous iff $f(K)$ is compact when $K$ is compact ? I know that if $f$ is continuous, then $f(K)$ is compact when $K$ is compact. But does the converse hold ? I'm talking especially for a function $f:\mathbb R\longrightarrow \mathbb R$, but a general answer would be good too.

Comment: Creators in mathematics are so extraordinarily smart than you can ensure that no, because if that were true, it would be a well-known theorem

Answer (score 8):

No, the converse is not true. Consider the function $f: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x)=1$ if $x \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $f(x)=0$ otherwise. Then $f$ is nowhere continuous, but the image of each compact subset $K$ of $\mathbb{R}$ is compact as finite sets are compact.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is no in general. However, in some 'nice' cases the answer is positive. See [this question on MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/223708/is-any-function-taking-compact-sets-to-compact-sets-and-connected-sets-to-conne).

Answer (score 1):

No.

Consider $f: \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x)=0$ if $x<0$ and $f(x)=1$ if $x\ge 0$.

Then, for *every* $X \subseteq \mathbb R$, we have that $f(X)$ is a finite set and so compact. But $f$ is not continuous.

Comment: Sir, what if $f$ has an inverse?

Answer (score 1):

There is a MathOverflow question which has been closed as off-topic (because it's regarded as a question belonging to math.SE), but which has [the following answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/223830) by [Lajos Soukup](https://mathoverflow.net/users/71011/lajos-soukup):

> There are highly non-trivial positive results.
>
> Let us call a function $f$ from a space $X$ into a space $Y$
>   **preserving** if the image of every compact subspace of $X$ is compact in $Y$ and the image of every connected subspace of $X$ is
>   connected in $Y$.
>
> McMillan  [On continuity conditions for functions, Pacific J. Math. 32
>   (1970) 479-494] proved the following result:
>
> **Theorem:** *If $X$ is Hausdorff, locally connected and Frechét, $Y$ is Hausdorff (e.g. if $X=Y=\mathbb R$), then any preserving function
>   $f:X\to Y$ is continuous.*
>
> For further  results see [Gerlits, Juhasz, Soukup, Szentmiklossy:
>   Characterizing continuity by preserving compactness and connectedness,
>   Top. Appl, 138 (2004), 21-44](http://ac.els-cdn.com/S0166864103002621/1-s2.0-S0166864103002621-main.pdf?_tid=d613d522-8d3b-11e5-9ec9-00000aacb361&acdnat=1447772564_7f13bdabf0eb738c0985ff887ddc95c5)
>
> Our main result is the following:
>
> **Theorem:**  If $X$ is any product of connected linearly ordered spaces (e.g., if $X = \mathbb R^\kappa$ ) and $f:X \to Y$ is a
>   preserving function into a regular space $Y$, then $f$ is continuous.